# Change the height of form input box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

I would like to adjust the height of the form input box and make the text almost touch the top and the bottom borders of the box. I tried adding some css, but had no luck. I'm looking for a bootstrap css solution.

```css
.form-group {
  height: 10px;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="input">First Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="input" placeholder="Enter text">
    </div>
```

In other words (or pictures), I want to change this

[image]

to this:

[image]

Comment: your CSS is just flat wrong. you do not use equal signs (`=`) you use colons (`:`), and if you are editing a class you need to put a `.` before the name, e.g. `.form-group`

Comment: Otherwise, I'm assuming you've checked the documentation available [on the Bootstrap Website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/)

Comment: I tried that, but I couldn't find how to adjust the height of the box

Comment: Are you trying to create a single-line input field or a multi-line input field? If you're going for the latter, I would use textarea instead of input.

Comment: you've tried using the sizing variant classes, e.g. `form-control-lg`?

Comment: No I'm not trying to create a multi-line input field. I want to reduce the height of the box, so it is more tight.

Comment: I've tried `form-control-lg`, but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Using Bootstrap only, your best bet would be:

Bootstrap v3

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#forms-control-sizes

Bootstrap v4

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#sizing

From there you can adjust the padding manually to reduce the gap between the top/bottom of the letters with the border of the input box.

Bootstrap v4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/

Bootstrap v3: You'll have to use CSS padding on the `<input>` element to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the recommended bootstrap solution and override **$input-height** variable in my custom.scss,
like so:

```
$input-height: 1rem;
```

(overriding bootstrap variables: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/)